# Masonry images overlapping issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

the title pretty much says everything, I did look into the images plugin from masonry yet I had no luck, I wonder if anyone could help?

The script does many things, it has the filter bit, the animation, show/hide, ajax to get the content etc etc. I'd be happy if anyone could investigate into why it is overlapping and how i could solve it based on the code below:

```
 jQuery(function(){
   jQuery('#container').masonry({
   itemSelector: '.box',
   animate: true
   });
  });



   (function ($) {
// Get all menu items with IDs starting with "filter-" and loop over them
$(".menu li[id|=filter]").each(function () {
    // Get the ID add extract the page class name from it (remove "filter-"       from it)
    var type = $(this).attr("id").replace("filter-", "");
    // Get the items in the "webbies" list with that class name
    var items = $("#container div[class~=" + type + "]");
    // Don't do anything if there aren't any
    if (items.length == 0) return;
    // Get a list of the other items in the list
    var others = $("#container>div:not([class~=" + type + "])");
    // Add a click event to the menu item
    $("a", this).click(function (e) {
        // Stop the link
        e.preventDefault();
        // Close open item
        if (openItem) {
            close(openItem);
        }
        items.removeClass("inactive").animate({opacity: 1});
        others.addClass("inactive").animate({opacity: 0.2});
    });
});

$(".reset-filter a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (openItem) close(openItem);
    $("div.box.inactive").removeClass("inactive").animate({opacity: 1});
});

var openItem;

// Opens an item
var open = function (item) {
    // Close open item
    if (openItem) close(openItem);
    item.addClass("loading");
    $("img", item).first().hide();
    item.width(340);
    item.height(600);
    if (!item.data('loaded')) {
        $("div.fader", item).load($("a", item).first().attr("href") + " #content", function () {
            stButtons.locateElements();
            stButtons.makeButtons();
            stWidget.init();
            $("#container").masonry('reloadItems', function () {
                $("div.fader", item).animate({opacity: 1}, function () {
                    item.removeClass("loading");
                    $('<a href="#"  class="close">Close</a>"').appendTo(this).click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        close(item);
                        $(document).scrollTo(   $("#navigation-block"), 600, {offset:-50} );
                    });
                    $("div.info", item).fadeIn("slow", function () {
                        $(document).scrollTo( $(".info"),  600, {offset:80} );
                    });
                });
            });
            item.data('loaded', true);
        });
    } else {
        item.removeClass("loading");
        $("#container").masonry('reloadItems', function () {
            $("div.fader", item).animate({opacity: 1}, function () {
                $("div.info", item).fadeIn("slow", function () {
                    $(document).scrollTo( $(".info"), 600,                    {offset:80} );
                });
            });
        });
    }

    // Set open item
    openItem = item;

};

// Closes an item
var close = function (item) {
    $("div.fader", item).animate({opacity: 0});
    $("div.info", item).hide();
    item.animate({width: 150, height: 100}, function () {
        $("img", item).first().fadeIn("slow");
        $("#container").masonry('reloadItems');
    });

    // Reset open item
    openItem = null;
};

$("#container div.box").each(function () {
    var item = $(this);
    item.data('loaded', false);
    $("div.fader", item).css("opacity", 0);
    $("a.close", item).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        close(item);
        $(document).scrollTo( $("#navigation-block"), 600, {offset:-50} );
    });
    $("a.showMe", item).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (item.hasClass("inactive")) return;
        open(item);
    });
}); 
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Comment: Maybe something to do with this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60635/images-overlapping-in-google-chrome/60636#60636

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 jQuery(function(){
   var $container = $('#container');
   $container.imagesLoaded( function () {
       itemSelector: '.box',
       animate: true
   });
  });
```

Source: [jQuery Masonry Images](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/images.html)

Comment: Better put, as my previous point isn't necessarily true, a function cannot be used like this.

Answer (score 10):

I've experienced the same problem and I developed 2 methods to combat it. First off reload the container after you have appended the onclick-image.

```
1. container.masonry('reload');
```

Second, and probably more important, dynamically correct the height of the surrounding div to match the height of the image:

```
2. // bricks correct height
   var brick = $("#marker #container .brick"); 
   brick.each(function() {
          var content = $(this).find(">div");
          var img = $(this).find("img");
           content.css({
            height: img.attr("height")
           });
        });
```

So my brick is looking like this:

```
  <div style="height: 284px; position: static; top: -133px;" class="test">  
       <a class="arrow" href="#" target="_self"><img class="img" src="test.jpg" width="374" height="284"></a>
  </div>
```

Edit: In your code you have the same problem, there is no height in the style.

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 330px; top: 280px;" class="box item 3d">
```

And it seems to me you have a problem with the width, too. I think you need to use a smaller width for the column. A good value would be the width of the small image and some border.

Comment: mm that makes sense and it is promising, thanks. Will have a try and reply back

Comment: This is only a valid solution if you already have image dimensions defined. If so, the box model will take care of any overlapping.  Setting height/width explicitly is superfluous.