# Hairline gaps between items in isotope-packery on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I am having a small issue with my isotope-packery layouts, where a very thin 1px or less line is appearing between certain items at some window sizes. Is there a way to eliminate this hairline gap?

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/juEsu.png (look between items 3 and 4)

I have a JSFiddle here to look at: http://jsfiddle.net/drawcard/akw6m9x1/
(resize the fiddle "window", so you can see the gaps)

```js
// external js:
// http://isotope.metafizzy.co/beta/isotope.pkgd.js

//packery js (no need to copy this over if you have it included)
/*!
 * Packery layout mode PACKAGED v1.1.0
 * sub-classes Packery
 * http://packery.metafizzy.co
 */

!function(a){function b(a){return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)"+a+"(\\s+|$)")}function c(a,b){var c=d(a,b)?f:e;c(a,b)}var d,e,f;"classList"in document.documentElement?(d=function(a,b){return a.classList.contains(b)},e=function(a,b){a.classList.add(b)},f=function(a,b){a.classList.remove(b)}):(d=function(a,c){return b(c).test(a.className)},e=function(a,b){d(a,b)||(a.className=a.className+" "+b)},f=function(a,c){a.className=a.className.replace(b(c)," ")});var g={hasClass:d,addClass:e,removeClass:f,toggleClass:c,has:d,add:e,remove:f,toggle:c};"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define("classie/classie",g):"object"==typeof exports?module.exports=g:a.classie=g}(window),function(a){function b(){function a(b){for(var c in a.defaults)this[c]=a.defaults[c];for(c in b)this[c]=b[c]}return c.Rect=a,a.defaults={x:0,y:0,width:0,height:0},a.prototype.contains=function(a){var b=a.width||0,c=a.height||0;return this.x<=a.x&&this.y<=a.y&&this.x+this.width>=a.x+b&&this.y+this.height>=a.y+c},a.prototype.overlaps=function(a){var b=this.x+this.width,c=this.y+this.height,d=a.x+a.width,e=a.y+a.height;return this.x<d&&b>a.x&&this.y<e&&c>a.y},a.prototype.getMaximalFreeRects=function(b){if(!this.overlaps(b))return!1;var c,d=[],e=this.x+this.width,f=this.y+this.height,g=b.x+b.width,h=b.y+b.height;return this.y<b.y&&(c=new a({x:this.x,y:this.y,width:this.width,height:b.y-this.y}),d.push(c)),e>g&&(c=new a({x:g,y:this.y,width:e-g,height:this.height}),d.push(c)),f>h&&(c=new a({x:this.x,y:h,width:this.width,height:f-h}),d.push(c)),this.x<b.x&&(c=new a({x:this.x,y:this.y,width:b.x-this.x,height:this.height}),d.push(c)),d},a.prototype.canFit=function(a){return this.width>=a.width&&this.height>=a.height},a}var c=a.Packery=function(){};"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define("packery/js/rect",b):"object"==typeof exports?module.exports=b():(a.Packery=a.Packery||{},a.Packery.Rect=b())}(window),function(a){function b(a){function b(a,b,c){this.width=a||0,this.height=b||0,this.sortDirection=c||"downwardLeftToRight",this.reset()}b.prototype.reset=function(){this.spaces=[],this.newSpaces=[];var b=new a({x:0,y:0,width:this.width,height:this.height});this.spaces.push(b),this.sorter=c[this.sortDirection]||c.downwardLeftToRight},b.prototype.pack=function(a){for(var b=0,c=this.spaces.length;c>b;b++){var d=this.spaces[b];if(d.canFit(a)){this.placeInSpace(a,d);break}}},b.prototype.placeInSpace=function(a,b){a.x=b.x,a.y=b.y,this.placed(a)},b.prototype.placed=function(a){for(var b=[],c=0,d=this.spaces.length;d>c;c++){var e=this.spaces[c],f=e.getMaximalFreeRects(a);f?b.push.apply(b,f):b.push(e)}this.spaces=b,this.mergeSortSpaces()},b.prototype.mergeSortSpaces=function(){b.mergeRects(this.spaces),this.spaces.sort(this.sorter)},b.prototype.addSpace=function(a){this.spaces.push(a),this.mergeSortSpaces()},b.mergeRects=function(a){for(var b=0,c=a.length;c>b;b++){var d=a[b];if(d){var e=a.slice(0);e.splice(b,1);for(var f=0,g=0,h=e.length;h>g;g++){var i=e[g],j=b>g?0:1;d.contains(i)&&(a.splice(g+j-f,1),f++)}}}return a};var c={downwardLeftToRight:function(a,b){return a.y-b.y||a.x-b.x},rightwardTopToBottom:function(a,b){return a.x-b.x||a.y-b.y}};return b}if("function"==typeof define&&define.amd)define("packery/js/packer",["./rect"],b);else if("object"==typeof exports)module.exports=b(require("./rect"));else{var c=a.Packery=a.Packery||{};c.Packer=b(c.Rect)}}(window),function(a){function b(a,b,c){var d=a("transform"),e=function(){b.Item.apply(this,arguments)};e.prototype=new b.Item;var f=e.prototype._create;return e.prototype._create=function(){f.call(this),this.rect=new c,this.placeRect=new c},e.prototype.dragStart=function(){this.getPosition(),this.removeTransitionStyles(),this.isTransitioning&&d&&(this.element.style[d]="none"),this.getSize(),this.isPlacing=!0,this.needsPositioning=!1,this.positionPlaceRect(this.position.x,this.position.y),this.isTransitioning=!1,this.didDrag=!1},e.prototype.dragMove=function(a,b){this.didDrag=!0;var c=this.layout.size;a-=c.paddingLeft,b-=c.paddingTop,this.positionPlaceRect(a,b)},e.prototype.dragStop=function(){this.getPosition();var a=this.position.x!==this.placeRect.x,b=this.position.y!==this.placeRect.y;this.needsPositioning=a||b,this.didDrag=!1},e.prototype.positionPlaceRect=function(a,b,c){this.placeRect.x=this.getPlaceRectCoord(a,!0),this.placeRect.y=this.getPlaceRectCoord(b,!1,c)},e.prototype.getPlaceRectCoord=function(a,b,c){var d=b?"Width":"Height",e=this.size["outer"+d],f=this.layout[b?"columnWidth":"rowHeight"],g=this.layout.size["inner"+d];b||(g=Math.max(g,this.layout.maxY),this.layout.rowHeight||(g-=this.layout.gutter));var h;if(f){f+=this.layout.gutter,g+=b?this.layout.gutter:0,a=Math.round(a/f);var i;i=this.layout.options.isHorizontal?b?"ceil":"floor":b?"floor":"ceil";var j=Math[i](g/f);j-=Math.ceil(e/f),h=j}else h=g-e;return a=c?a:Math.min(a,h),a*=f||1,Math.max(0,a)},e.prototype.copyPlaceRectPosition=function(){this.rect.x=this.placeRect.x,this.rect.y=this.placeRect.y},e.prototype.removeElem=function(){this.element.parentNode.removeChild(this.element),this.layout.packer.addSpace(this.rect),this.emitEvent("remove",[this])},e}"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define("packery/js/item",["get-style-property/get-style-property","outlayer/outlayer","./rect"],b):"object"==typeof exports?module.exports=b(require("desandro-get-style-property"),require("outlayer"),require("./rect")):a.Packery.Item=b(a.getStyleProperty,a.Outlayer,a.Packery.Rect)}(window),function(a){function b(a,b,c,d,e,f){function g(a,b){return a.position.y-b.position.y||a.position.x-b.position.x}function h(a,b){return a.position.x-b.position.x||a.position.y-b.position.y}var i=c.create("packery");return i.Item=f,i.prototype._create=function(){c.prototype._create.call(this),this.packer=new e,this.stamp(this.options.stamped);var a=this;this.handleDraggabilly={dragStart:function(b){a.itemDragStart(b.element)},dragMove:function(b){a.itemDragMove(b.element,b.position.x,b.position.y)},dragEnd:function(b){a.itemDragEnd(b.element)}},this.handleUIDraggable={start:function(b){a.itemDragStart(b.currentTarget)},drag:function(b,c){a.itemDragMove(b.currentTarget,c.position.left,c.position.top)},stop:function(b){a.itemDragEnd(b.currentTarget)}}},i.prototype._resetLayout=function(){this.getSize(),this._getMeasurements();var a=this.packer;this.options.isHorizontal?(a.width=Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,a.height=this.size.innerHeight+this.gutter,a.sortDirection="rightwardTopToBottom"):(a.width=this.size.innerWidth+this.gutter,a.height=Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,a.sortDirection="downwardLeftToRight"),a.reset(),this.maxY=0,this.maxX=0},i.prototype._getMeasurements=function(){this._getMeasurement("columnWidth","width"),this._getMeasurement("rowHeight","height"),this._getMeasurement("gutter","width")},i.prototype._getItemLayoutPosition=function(a){return this._packItem(a),a.rect},i.prototype._packItem=function(a){this._setRectSize(a.element,a.rect),this.packer.pack(a.rect),this._setMaxXY(a.rect)},i.prototype._setMaxXY=function(a){this.maxX=Math.max(a.x+a.width,this.maxX),this.maxY=Math.max(a.y+a.height,this.maxY)},i.prototype._setRectSize=function(a,c){var d=b(a),e=d.outerWidth,f=d.outerHeight;if(e||f){var g=this.columnWidth+this.gutter,h=this.rowHeight+this.gutter;e=this.columnWidth?Math.ceil(e/g)*g:e+this.gutter,f=this.rowHeight?Math.ceil(f/h)*h:f+this.gutter}c.width=Math.min(e,this.packer.width),c.height=Math.min(f,this.packer.height)},i.prototype._getContainerSize=function(){return this.options.isHorizontal?{width:this.maxX-this.gutter}:{height:this.maxY-this.gutter}},i.prototype._manageStamp=function(a){var b,c=this.getItem(a);if(c&&c.isPlacing)b=c.placeRect;else{var e=this._getElementOffset(a);b=new d({x:this.options.isOriginLeft?e.left:e.right,y:this.options.isOriginTop?e.top:e.bottom})}this._setRectSize(a,b),this.packer.placed(b),this._setMaxXY(b)},i.prototype.sortItemsByPosition=function(){var a=this.options.isHorizontal?h:g;this.items.sort(a)},i.prototype.fit=function(a,b,c){var d=this.getItem(a);d&&(this._getMeasurements(),this.stamp(d.element),d.getSize(),d.isPlacing=!0,b=void 0===b?d.rect.x:b,c=void 0===c?d.rect.y:c,d.positionPlaceRect(b,c,!0),this._bindFitEvents(d),d.moveTo(d.placeRect.x,d.placeRect.y),this.layout(),this.unstamp(d.element),this.sortItemsByPosition(),d.isPlacing=!1,d.copyPlaceRectPosition())},i.prototype._bindFitEvents=function(a){function b(){d++,2===d&&c.emitEvent("fitComplete",[c,a])}var c=this,d=0;a.on("layout",function(){return b(),!0}),this.on("layoutComplete",function(){return b(),!0})},i.prototype.resize=function(){var a=b(this.element),c=this.size&&a,d=this.options.isHorizontal?"innerHeight":"innerWidth";c&&a[d]===this.size[d]||this.layout()},i.prototype.itemDragStart=function(a){this.stamp(a);var b=this.getItem(a);b&&b.dragStart()},i.prototype.itemDragMove=function(a,b,c){function d(){f.layout(),delete f.dragTimeout}var e=this.getItem(a);e&&e.dragMove(b,c);var f=this;this.clearDragTimeout(),this.dragTimeout=setTimeout(d,40)},i.prototype.clearDragTimeout=function(){this.dragTimeout&&clearTimeout(this.dragTimeout)},i.prototype.itemDragEnd=function(b){var c,d=this.getItem(b);if(d&&(c=d.didDrag,d.dragStop()),!d||!c&&!d.needsPositioning)return void this.unstamp(b);a.add(d.element,"is-positioning-post-drag");var e=this._getDragEndLayoutComplete(b,d);d.needsPositioning?(d.on("layout",e),d.moveTo(d.placeRect.x,d.placeRect.y)):d&&d.copyPlaceRectPosition(),this.clearDragTimeout(),this.on("layoutComplete",e),this.layout()},i.prototype._getDragEndLayoutComplete=function(b,c){var d=c&&c.needsPositioning,e=0,f=d?2:1,g=this;return function(){return e++,e!==f?!0:(c&&(a.remove(c.element,"is-positioning-post-drag"),c.isPlacing=!1,c.copyPlaceRectPosition()),g.unstamp(b),g.sortItemsByPosition(),d&&g.emitEvent("dragItemPositioned",[g,c]),!0)}},i.prototype.bindDraggabillyEvents=function(a){a.on("dragStart",this.handleDraggabilly.dragStart),a.on("dragMove",this.handleDraggabilly.dragMove),a.on("dragEnd",this.handleDraggabilly.dragEnd)},i.prototype.bindUIDraggableEvents=function(a){a.on("dragstart",this.handleUIDraggable.start).on("drag",this.handleUIDraggable.drag).on("dragstop",this.handleUIDraggable.stop)},i.Rect=d,i.Packer=e,i}"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define("packery/js/packery",["classie/classie","get-size/get-size","outlayer/outlayer","./rect","./packer","./item"],b):"object"==typeof exports?module.exports=b(require("desandro-classie"),require("get-size"),require("outlayer"),require("./rect"),require("./packer"),require("./item")):a.Packery=b(a.classie,a.getSize,a.Outlayer,a.Packery.Rect,a.Packery.Packer,a.Packery.Item)}(window),function(a){function b(a,b){for(var c in b)a[c]=b[c];return a}function c(a,c,d){var e=a.create("packery"),f=e.prototype._getElementOffset,g=e.prototype._getMeasurement;b(e.prototype,c.prototype),e.prototype._getElementOffset=f,e.prototype._getMeasurement=g;var h=e.prototype._resetLayout;e.prototype._resetLayout=function(){this.packer=this.packer||new c.Packer,h.apply(this,arguments)};var i=e.prototype._getItemLayoutPosition;e.prototype._getItemLayoutPosition=function(a){return a.rect=a.rect||new c.Rect,i.call(this,a)};var j=e.prototype._manageStamp;return e.prototype._manageStamp=function(){this.options.isOriginLeft=this.isotope.options.isOriginLeft,this.options.isOriginTop=this.isotope.options.isOriginTop,j.apply(this,arguments)},e.prototype.needsResizeLayout=function(){var a=d(this.element),b=this.size&&a,c=this.options.isHorizontal?"innerHeight":"innerWidth";return b&&a[c]!==this.size[c]},e}"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["isotope/js/layout-mode","packery/js/packery","get-size/get-size"],c):"object"==typeof exports?module.exports=c(require("isotope-layout/js/layout-mode"),require("packery"),require("get-size")):c(a.Isotope.LayoutMode,a.Packery,a.getSize)}(window);

//Site Code
$( function() {
  $('.container').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    layoutMode: 'packery',
    cellsByRow: {
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
    }
  });
});

$(window).load(function(){
    $('.container').isotope('layout');
})
```

```css
.container { margin-top: 2em; margin-bottom: 2em; width: 100%; /*background-color:#ff9900;*/}

/* clear fix */ 
.container:after { content: ''; display: block; clear: both; }

.item, .grid-sizer { width: 50%; height:0; padding-bottom:50%; opacity:0.6 position:relative; box-sizing:border-box;}
.item img {max-width:100%;height:auto;position:absolute;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;}
.big {width:100%; height:0; padding-bottom:100%;}
.item:before{content:'';padding-top:50%;display:block;}
.item .contents{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;opacity:0.6; padding:20px;}

/*styling items so we can see them in demo*/
.item:nth-child(odd) .contents{background-color:#ccc}
.item:nth-child(even) .contents{background-color:#aaa}

@media (min-width: 480px) { 
    .grid-sizer, .item {width: 25%; height: 0; padding-bottom:25%;}   
    .big {width: 50%; height: 0; padding-bottom:50%;}   
}

@media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .grid-sizer, .item {width: 12.5%; height: 0; padding-bottom:12.5%;} 
    .big {width: 25%; height: 0; padding-bottom:25%;}   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Isotope - masonry element sizing columnWidth</h1>

<div class="container">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/512/cats/1" />
        <div class="contents">
            <h2>1</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="item big">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/512/cats/2" />
        <div class="contents">
            <h2>2</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/512/cats/3" />
        <div class="contents">
            <h2>3</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/512/cats/4" />
        <div class="contents">
            <h2>4</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/512/cats/5" />
        <div class="contents">
            <h2>5</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="item big">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/512/cats/6" />
        <div class="contents">
            <h2>6</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="item big">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/512/cats/7" />
        <div class="contents">
            <h2>7</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/512/cats/8" />
        <div class="contents">
            <h2>8</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/512/cats/9" />
        <div class="contents">
            <h2>9</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="item big">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/512/cats/10" />
        <div class="contents">
            <h2>10</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sub-pixel rounding?  Or the binary representation of fractions?  The elements are positioned absolutely in pixels, but their dimensions are defined in percentages.  In some cases this absolute offset doesn't account for the width or height of all the elements in it.  Maybe.  :)

Comment: packery has an opt-in to position the elements using percentages (`"percentPosition": true`) but the problem persists, which leads me to think it's the browser layout engine accumulating rounding errors: http://jsfiddle.net/akw6m9x1/20/

Comment: Is anyone actually seeing this below screen sizes of 2426...

Comment: @CayceK I can see the problem in the jsfidle window as narrow as ~770px: http://i.imgur.com/o4HQXdz.png (no. 9 is smaller than it should be by a fraction of a pixel in both dimensions). At ~850px it's between 3 and 4, then at ~900px on the left edge of 6.

Comment: @pawel thanks! I am seeing it for sure now. I thought I was looking closely, but I missed it probably moving too fast or too far!

Answer (score 3):

@Phpdevpad suggested I define dimensions for the image, however if I put the dimensions in the picture she'd be locked. My solution was to put the image as the background from itemSelector and define a fixed height for the itemSelector.

Comment: If my answer is helpful please consider to accept and/or upvote/reward me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Caio Kawasaki - could you kindly provide a code example of how you're achieving this? I'm stuck on this issue but can't work out what you mean from 'put the image as the background for itemSelector'.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from developer console, Isotope positions the items with an absolute position and absolute left and top pixel values, which sometimes appears to be one pixel off. That seems to be a bug with Isotope.

I suggest you'd report that as a bug here: https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/issues

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the image width and height attribute. I had a similar bug with masonry. Please check this question:[Masonry images overlapping issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971258/masonry-images-overlapping-issue/7971857#7971857). The author of the plugin has left a mysterious comment to my solution. Sorry I can't help.

Answer (score 1):

The isotope library doesn't use decimal numbers when it's positioning the images. So if an image should be at 150,125px, it just puts it at 150px. This causes the small spaces between the images.

I've tested this with your jsfiddle and it fixes the issue.

Comment: Did you fix the library? Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Phpdevpad I wish I could fix the library haha. Let's say we have a container of 500px in which isotope wants to make 8 columns. Each column should be 62,5px, right? 
But if isotope tries to put an item in the first column it doesn't put it at 62,5px, it puts it at 62px. And that's how the small spaces start appearing between the images.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the issue by getting setting the width of the packery container to be divisible by the num of columns.

This will cause gaps at the side of the packery container in your layout. So either offset the packery container by half the gap to get it in the middle, or oversize your packery container so it goes off the page (this will only be by a few pixels so you probably won't notice)

Answer (score 1):

```css
img {
  display: block;
}
```

Solved the problem for me.